# Непонятная проблема с margin + div

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Имеется простой код, который должен демонстрировать вёрстку двух колонок. И две колонки даже есть, но почему-то непонятно по какой причине одна из них сдвинулась вверх без видимых на то причин.

Вёрстка классическая: берутся две колонки, им задаётся width и float+overflow.
Привожу код:

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  /*    margin-top: 0;*/
}

.cardstorage {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
}

.main {
  width: 75%;
}

.rightbar {
  width: 25%;
}

.card {
  background-color: white;
  /*    padding: 20px;*/
  /*    margin-top: 10px;*/
}

.card * {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="main cardstorage">

    <div class="card">
      <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
      <h2 class="meta">Title description, Dec 7, 2017</h2>
      <img src="" alt="">
      <p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur autem dolorem fuga inventore, expedita. Enim, hic. Aliquid magni, doloremque praesentium dolore, quisquam, aspernatur minus in natus doloribus accusamus asperiores id.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
      <h2 class="meta">Title description, Dec 7, 2017</h2>
      <img src="" alt="">
      <p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur autem dolorem fuga inventore, expedita. Enim, hic. Aliquid magni, doloremque praesentium dolore, quisquam, aspernatur minus in natus doloribus accusamus asperiores id.</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="rightbar cardstorage">
    <div class="rightcard card">INFO</div>
    <div class="rightcard card">INFO</div>
    <p class="content"></p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Class main 75%, а класс rightbar 25%. Если не исппользовать обнуление стилей, то результат будет всегда таким. Рекомендую reset.css Не помню какой параметр тебе мешает, но посмотри на границы дивов.

Comment: @Алексей А что не так? 75%+25%=100%

Comment: как тебе уже сказали, у каждого блока есть небольшой отступ. Его необходимо убрать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас ничего никуда не сдвинулось, просто Вы background-color: white задаёте несколько странным образом, потому и кажется визуально, что блоки на разной высоте. Либо задайте фон самим плавающим блокам, либо уберите margin-top у title (я в примере сделал и то, и другое)

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  /*    margin-top: 0;*/
}

.title {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.cardstorage {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: white;
}

.main {
  width: 75%;
}

.rightbar {
  width: 25%;
}

.card {
  background-color: white;
  /*    padding: 20px;*/
  /*    margin-top: 10px;*/
}

.card * {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="main cardstorage">

    <div class="card">
      <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
      <h2 class="meta">Title description, Dec 7, 2017</h2>
      <img src="" alt="">
      <p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur autem dolorem fuga inventore, expedita. Enim, hic. Aliquid magni, doloremque praesentium dolore, quisquam, aspernatur minus in natus doloribus accusamus asperiores id.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
      <h2 class="meta">Title description, Dec 7, 2017</h2>
      <img src="" alt="">
      <p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur autem dolorem fuga inventore, expedita. Enim, hic. Aliquid magni, doloremque praesentium dolore, quisquam, aspernatur minus in natus doloribus accusamus asperiores id.</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="rightbar cardstorage">
    <div class="rightcard card">INFO</div>
    <div class="rightcard card">INFO</div>
    <p class="content"></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Хм. Действительно работает. Но не подскажете, откуда у `.title` взялся ненулевой `margin-top`?

Comment: @witaway, по умолчанию у всех заголовков есть margin (причём в разных браузерах эти отступы могут различаться). Чтобы таких проблем не возникало, обычно используют какой-нибудь reset.css или normalize.css для обнуления предустановленных свойств элементов

Comment: Кстати говоря, а не расскажете, что странного в моём способе определения `background-color: white` и как можно сделать лучше?

Comment: @witaway, ну, я просто не очень понимаю, зачем изначально всем элементам задавать background-color: #f1f1f1, а потом у отдельных элементов "обелять" этот фон (у Вас селекторы .card и .card *)

Comment: Сначала задаю всем `#f1f1f1`, чтобы сделать задний фон у страницы, а потом уже забеляю у отдельных элементов этот фон, чтобы получились "карточки".

Comment: Похоже, вы предлагаете делать фон `#f1f1f1` только для body? Только сейчас догадался, что так можно.

Comment: @witaway, именно :)